# Android - Google+ login

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm following the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in?hl=pt-PT and i'm having some dificulties on enabling the login.

Right on step 2, i have copied to code to my login fragment (where i have the facebook login working smooth), and i get an error on Plus client:

```
- mPlusClient cannot be resolved to a variable
- The method setVisibleActivities(String, String) is undefined for the type PlusClient.Builder
- The constructor PlusClient.Builder(SplashFragment, SplashFragment, SplashFragment) is undefined
```

I cant understand where i'm failing, as i've followed the tutorial several times.

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/#more-157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial had been updated in english version. You can check it from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started?hl=en.
They use GoogleApiClient now.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
```

Comment: Just another question, i'm having an error with this: findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this); how can I fix it?

Comment: @Cafn If you are having a NullPointerException on findViewById then the ID you are finding is not existing... or the context of R file is wrong

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Portuguese version of that page has not been updated to the latest API, hence you are getting errors attempting to use the old API (which has since been deprecated). Consider using the [english version](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Social-Auth Library to integrate multiple social platforms with ease...

> SocialAuth Android is an Android version of popular SocialAuth Java library. Now you do not need to integrate multiple SDKs if you want to integrate your application with multiple social networks. You just need to add few lines of code after integrating the SocialAuth Android library in your app.

[Social Auth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)